# Select control data-binding doesnt work in IE9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, select, data-binding

I have a dropdown control data-bound as follows:

```
 <select name="trafficGroup" class="form-control input-sm"
                    ng-model="monitoringProbe.tdmCapture.selectedTDMCard.timeSlotProperties.trafficGroup"
                    required
                    ng-style="{'width':'100%'}"
                    ng-disabled="!monitoringProbe.tdmCapture.selectedTDMCard.isEditMode"
                    ng-if="monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.trafficGroups.length > 0">
            <option value="{{tg.id}}"  ng-repeat="tg in monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.trafficGroups" > {{tg.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

I explicitly set the value for `monitoringProbe.tdmCapture.selectedTDMCard.timeSlotProperties.trafficGroup`, as follows because otherwise its default value gets empty:

```
          if(tdmCapture.selectedTDMCard.timeSlotProperties.trafficGroup == 0)
                    tdmCapture.selectedTDMCard.timeSlotProperties.trafficGroup = app.meta.monitoringprobe.tdmCaptureTabData.trafficGroups[1];
```

This works fine in all browsers except in IE9. in IE9 what I see in dropdown is {{ tg.name }}

I added `ng-if="monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.trafficGroups.length > 0"` to avoid this, but still the issue is there.

Any idea how to fix-it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ng-repeat with the option tag, you can use the [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) attribute of the select directive. I'm not positive if this will resolve the issue you're seeing, but it's typically the better approach.

```
<select ng-options="tg.id as tg.name for tg in monitoringProbeTDMCaptureData.trafficGroups">
</select>
```

If you want the default value to be empty, you just include a single option tag with an empty value.

```
<select ...>
    <option value=""></option>
<select>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Actually I earlier had ng-options bound, but I changed it to ng-repeat because there was an issue with the default value binding. Now both problems seem to be resolved.